# Arrays Issue, not copying properly

Tags: java, arrays

This is the code i am working with to take in rows, from a csv, store them into an array of strings called userDetails, it will then, from this data take all the values of userDetails from the 4th value onwards(userDetails[3]), and put them into a 2 dimensional array of integers called scores.

```
private void loadFromCSVFile() 
    {
        String path = "res/users.csv";
        BufferedReader br = null;
        String row = "";
        String DELIMETER = ",";
        int[][] scores = new int[3][9];
        try {

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
            while ((row = br.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                String[] userDetails = row.split(DELIMETER);

                int i = 3;
                for (int x = 0 ; x <= 2 ; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = 0 ; y <= 8 ; y++)
                    {
                        scores[x][y] = Integer.valueOf(userDetails[i] );
                        i++;
                    }
                } 

                user = new User( userDetails[0] , userDetails[1] , userDetails[2], scores);
                LoginChecker.Users.add(user);
            }


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

The line :

```
user = new User( userDetails[0] , userDetails[1] , userDetails[2], scores);
LoginChecker.Users.add(user);
```

creates a new instance of the User class, and passes in 3 strings (first = username, second = password , third = user type(whether a teacher, student, or admin)), along with the 3 Strings, it passes the Integer array 'scores'.

This code is so that later in the program i can use the code:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i <= LoginChecker.Users.size() - 1 ; i++)
        {
            if (LoginChecker.Users.get(i).getUser().toLowerCase().equals(this.USERNAME))
            {
                System.out.println("Name: " + LoginChecker.Users.get(i).getUser().toLowerCase() + "  Score: " + LoginChecker.Users.get(i).getScores()[0][0] );
            }
        }
```

where this.USERNAME is a string of the user that is logged in, in theory the above code should get the first score of the array (which is [0][0]) for the user in question, and print it, but instead it only displays the score of the last person in the csv.

For example if the csv contains:

Person 1,Password,Student,1,2,3, etc

Person 2,Password,Student,10,9,8, etc

No matter who you log in as, it will always display 10 as the first score.

Any help would be appreciated, sorry for the long read, if you need any more info about the program  just ask, ill be checking this reasonably regularly until i find a solution.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Show us `User`. (`static`)

Comment: The problem is you are using the same `scores[][]` for all your users. You should create a new instance in your `while` loop for each user...

Comment: @brso05 I'm around. I'll review once the OP updates their question with more details.

Comment: I am not sure, why you need two `for` loops, what is the use of outer for loop `for (int x = 0 ; x <= 2 ; x++)` ... As per my understanding inner for loop is responsible for reading 9 score values from csv for one student

Answer (score 2):

You are using the same `scores[][]` for all your users. You should create a new instance of the `scores[][]` for each user:

```
while ((row = br.readLine()) != null) 
{
    String[] userDetails = row.split(DELIMETER);
    int[][] scores = new int[3][9];************************************
    int i = 3;
    for (int x = 0 ; x <= 2 ; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0 ; y <= 8 ; y++)
        {
            scores[x][y] = Integer.valueOf(userDetails[i] );
            i++;
        }
    } 

    user = new User( userDetails[0] , userDetails[1] , userDetails[2], scores);
    LoginChecker.Users.add(user);
}
```

Comment: @JacobGroves `scores[][]` you are reusing it it will be the same for all `Users` that is why it always shows your last `User`. Did you even try the code?

Comment: @JacobGroves they are all pointing to the same `scores[][]` array.

Comment: @JacobGroves look at the code I posted and try it see if it works. Look at all the ****************************** you need to initialize your `scores[][]` down there in the `while` loop...

Comment: Ok, thank you, this has worked, but can you please explain why it doesn't work, in my eyes, this code should use the same array, but every time it makes a new user, it has different contents? so all the users are made with the same array, it has just been re-written, why is that not the case

Comment: @JacobGroves Because arrays are like objects in the sense they are referenced not like primitives.  When you create a new user you are `user = new User( userDetails[0] , userDetails[1] , userDetails[2], scores);` passing the reference to `scores[][]` to the new object.  All your new objects will point to the same array in memory.  You must create a new `instance` for each user object so they have their own `array` in memory. With the way you were doing it before if you update one `Users` `score[][]` it will update all `Users` `score[][]'s` because they all point to the same array in memory...

Comment: @JacobGroves I hope that helps clear it up...just remember `Arrays` are like `Objects` in the sense that they are both `referenced`. Feel free to mark this as correct if it helped you.

Comment: @JacobGroves you create a `new User()` you also have to create a `scores = new int[3][9]`. You have to create a new `Array` for the same reason you have to create a new `User` object. If you re-used your `User` object all your `Users` in your `Users` `List` would be the same they would all point to the same `User`.

Comment: That makes complete sense, i'm pretty sure i knew this, my mistake, thanks for the help.